# Microsoft Graph API - How to Filter SharePoint sites by Site Type?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

SharePoint Admins in Microsoft 365 can create Team Sites and Communication Sites [using the admin center.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/create-site-collection)

In addition, individual users can have [Personal Sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/my-sites-overview) (Otherwise known as *My Sites*)

Using the Microsoft Graph .NET SDK I can retrieve all sites like this:-

```
await client.Sites.Request().GetAsync();
```

However this appears to include all Team, Personal and Communication Sites. Is there a way to limit the request to only one type of site, or detect the type of each site returned from the query? I could not find anything in the documentation about this.

*Edit:* If there's a way to get this information via SharePoint CSOM, I would be interested in that too

Comment: Hi Rob, unfortunately this is not available as of now but there is a [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40632391-onedrive-sites) already raised. Please upvote it so that this feature may be implemented in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not available as of now but there is a [uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/40632391-onedrive-sites) already raised. Please upvote it so that this feature may be implemented in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it can help you but I found a workaround how to differentiate between a team/communication site and a personal site.
A personal site contains in the **WebUrl** field the string `"my.sharepoint.com/personal/"`, then after you make the call:
 `var sites = await client.Sites.Request().GetAsync();`
 you can use this filter to retrieve only personal site:
 `var personalSites = sites.Where(s => s.WebUrl.Contains("my.sharepoint.com/personal/"))`;
 (Microsoft does not allow to use a filter on this request directly, so this is the reason why I used the filter after fetching all sites.)

Comment: Are we 100% certain that the URL will always have `-my` in the first part of the host, no matter the language?